# Why does Dr. Cox from Scrubs hate Hugh Jackman?

Tags: scrubs

I distinctly remember at least 2 episodes of Scrubs where Dr. Cox insults Hugh Jackman (implied that Hugh is a bad actor) and does anyone know the reason why?
I haven't been able to find a clear answer on this...

Comment: This sounds like fishing for trivia to me.

Comment: Is this a reputable source http://www.aoltv.com/2006/05/16/john-c-mcginley-the-tv-squad-interview/ ?

Comment: yes, you should post it as an answer with a link to the source

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: Isn't this whole site about trivia?

Comment: @sharptooth: thanks for the link! Please make it into an answer so I can upvote/accept it.

Comment: @djm: Theres trivia and theres trivia that adds to the plot. This one is the former kind. And I beg to disagree that "_this whole site is about trivia_".

Comment: The actor who played Cox was in the running to play Wolverine, even to the point of almost having got the job.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?  Otherwise this is just speculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Cox#Character_profile) has surprisingly thorough articles on *Scrubs*:

> Cox harbors an intense hatred for Hugh Jackman, even going so far as to mention him frequently in his rants about things he hates throughout the series. According to a 2006 interview with McGinley, Cox's reason for hating Jackman may be because Bill Lawrence envies the actor's talent.

This section is sourced as coming from [this interview](http://www.aoltv.com/2006/05/16/john-c-mcginley-the-tv-squad-interview/).  Bill Lawrence is the creator and show-runner of *Scrubs*.